# Javascript unexpected behaviors

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects, console.log, firefox-developer-tools, google-developers-console

there are some behaviors I don't understand in Javascript :

1. Why `console.log(011666)` logged `5046` ?
2. Why `typeof typeof 500` logged `string` ?

Comment: A number starting with `0` is interpreted as octal number. `typeof 500` returns a string. The type of a string is `'string'`

Comment: This thing with leading zero making number octal is luckily being slowly fixed. ES6 introduced octals prefixed with `0o` (zero followed by 'o' for 'octal'). I'm happy to see JavaScript's idiocracy being addressed.

Comment: @RoboRobok That's not just JavaScript. Multiple languages have this. It's at least C, C++ and PHP and probably more.

Comment: Don't know about other languages, but it's just dumb. Why octal and not binary, for example? Or just decimal? It's not clear what it does when you read it without knowing this random fact that it's actually octal.

Comment: Duplicate of [Why JavaScript treats a number as octal if it has a leading zero](/q/37003770/4642212) and [duplicate](//google.com/search?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+js+typeof+typeof+is+string) of [typeof typeof x returns string and not object since type of null is object](/q/43171010/4642212).

Comment: @RoboRobok I'd say JavaScript has more serious problems than a very common number convention, e.g. `{} + {} === NaN`

Comment: @jabaa of course, I completely agree that these other problems are more serious. Nevertheless, my opinion is that 0-prefixed octals are stupid too. They are begging for hard-to-find bugs.

Comment: @jabaa `({} + {})` is `"[object Object][object Object]"`. Are you referring to the object–block syntax ambiguity itself?

Comment: @SebastianSimon I was referring to https://www.destroyallsoftware.com/talks/wat without checking it but obviously I have misunderstood something.

Comment: @SebastianSimon `{} + {} === NaN` in the Firefox dev tools console.

Comment: @jabaa That’s only because it’s interpreted as `{}; +{};` which is an empty block statement, then a unary plus applied to an object (which is coerced to a primitive, but that’s `"[object Object]"`, which isn’t a numeric string, so the result is `NaN`). All explained in [What is the explanation for these bizarre JavaScript behaviours mentioned in the 'Wat' talk for CodeMash 2012?](/q/9032856/4642212). Also, `{} + {} === NaN` is impossible… you mean `isNaN(+{})`, which isn’t really that mysterious.

Comment: @SebastianSimon Thanks. Good to learn about reasons for this behavior.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. A number starting with `0` is interpreted as octal number. A simpler example:

```js
console.log(010);
```

2. `typeof 500` returns a string `'number'`. The type of a string `'number'` is `'string'`.

```js
console.log(typeof 500);
console.log(typeof 'number');
```